# Add new data column

Tags: sql

How can I add new edited column into an existing query?

My query returns this result:

```
product_name    task_state  operation_code
------------------------------------------
KABY LAKE U 2+2 NULL        7571
KABY LAKE U 2+2 FUTURE WIP  7571
KABY LAKE U 2+2 NULL        6881
KABY LAKE U 2+2 NULL        7571
KABY LAKE U 2+2 NULL        7460
KABY LAKE U 2+2 NULL        7571
KABY LAKE U 2+2 NULL        6881
KABY LAKE U 2+2 FUTURE WIP  7571
```

and I want to replace all 'NULL' (empty cells and not 'NULL' txt) to "Done".

All rest of the data under "tasks_state" can be paste as is to new column.

At the end I hope the query results will be like this:

```
product_name    task_state  operation_code  Task status
-----------------------------------------------------------
KABY LAKE U 2+2 NULL        7571            Done
KABY LAKE U 2+2 FUTURE WIP  7571            FUTURE WIP
KABY LAKE U 2+2 NULL        6881            Done
KABY LAKE U 2+2 NULL        7571            Done
KABY LAKE U 2+2 NULL        7460            Done
KABY LAKE U 2+2 NULL        7571            Done
KABY LAKE U 2+2 NULL        6881            Done
KABY LAKE U 2+2 FUTURE WIP  7571            FUTURE WIP
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us your original query please so that we can suggest the modification required.

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**NULLIF**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms177562.aspx)

Try this

```
SELECT NULLIF(task_state ,'Done') FROM YourTable
```

Query Would be

```
SELECT product_name,NULLIF(task_state ,'Done'),operation_code,[Task status]
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: I get the answer (which is wrong because of confusion between `NULLIF()` and `IFNULL()`.  I don't get the upvote.

Comment: NULLIF Returns a null value if the two specified expressions are equal. NULLIF returns the first expression if the two expressions are not equal. If the expressions are equal, NULLIF returns a null value of the type of the first expression. NULLIF is equivalent to a searched CASE function in which the two expressions are equal and the resulting expression is NULL.

Comment: ISNULL Replaces NULL with the specified replacement value. The value of check_expression is returned if it is not NULL; otherwise, replacement_value is returned after it is implicitly converted to the type of check_expression, if the types are different.

Comment: Thanks, but im getting the same results at new column.

Comment: How can I give name for the new column?

Comment: @Coldfire Use `As` Keyword for new column name

Comment: `SELECT product_name,NULLIF(task_state ,'Done') As ColumnName ,operation_code,[Task status]
FROM YourTable`

Answer (score 1):

The best function to use is `COALESCE()` which is ANSI standard:

```
SELECT COALESCE(task_state, 'Done')
FROM t;
```

If the text also contains `'NULL'`, I would switch to `CASE:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN task_state IS NULL or task_state = 'NULL'
             THEN 'Done' ELSE task_state
        END) as "Task Status"
```